# Can only create on citrix application session per server

Tags: citrix, session

We have 3 Citrix presentation servers.
These servers are each hosting an application.
We can access the application fine.
However, if I access it, I can only open one session of the application on each server.

But if I try to open a fourth session, load balancing chooses one of the three, let's say number 1, it will close the first session and allow this new fourth session to take it over.
That way I always end up with three sessions.

However strangely, if I try the same credentials at a different site, I am able to have as many sessions as I like. Our client software is the same version and configuration as far as we can tell (we have a SOE).

Any ideas on what it could be?